# Unit test app delegate applicationWillResignActive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing

Has anyone found a way of unit testing of App Delegate message applicationWillResignActive.  I need to basically start simulator and then switch to springboard and then check a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried testing it with Instruments and UI Automation? (example: http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/07/03/working-with-uiautomation/)